# Require files with scope

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to give a scope to a file loaded with `require` node.js ?

For example:

**main.js**

```
var scope = {
    message: "Hello World",
};

require('./echo.js', scope);
```

**echo.js**

```
console.log(message);
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

I know i'm supposed to use `module` functionnalities, but this is a corner case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to pass it into the module then you can do it like this.

```
var scope = {
    message: "Hello World"
};

require('./echo.js')(scope);
```

echo.js:

```
module.exports = function(obj){
    console.log(obj.message);
}
```

It's the only way unless you declare scope a global variable. **Not recommended** due to polluting the global namespace.

```
global.scope = {
    message: "Hello World"
}
require('./echo.js');
```

echo.js:

```
console.log(global.scope.message);
```